# Create a relational database from a nested JSON

Tags: python, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

So I pulled **A LOT** of data from Riot because I wanted to get game information and parse/do data analytics on it, and also be able to pull it into a website, so I opted to use PostgreSQL but I'm having a lot of trouble with the structure of the tables.

Below is an example of the nested JSON that I pulled from this [API](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11rF2PEVjz4-g2_YAOslKBwCVxSGZTitQ/view?usp=sharing)

The biggest thing that I'm running into is I'm pretty new to databases in general and I'm not great at understanding the concepts, I've been looking through tutorials online but I just can't seem to wrap my head around foreign keys.

If I have a nested JSON that is identified as a specific game instance through the game_id, say,

```
{ 
    game_id: 123456
    ...
}
```

and there are multiple nested components that also have keys that I want to store separately in other tables.

Say for instance,

```
{
    game_id: 123456
    ...
    {
        team_id: 123456
        ...
            {
                participant_id: 123456
                ...
            }
     }
}
```

Should then each game table, team table, and participant table then have a foreign key such that game table has a foreign key to the team table, and the team table has a foreign key to the participant table?

For instance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE games (
    game_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id SERIAL REFERENCES game_teams(team_id),
    ...
    )

CREATE TABLE game_teams(
    team_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    participant_id SERIAL REFERENCES game_participants(participant_id),
    ...
    )

CREATE TABLE game_participants(
    participant_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    stats_id SERIAL REFERENCES game_participants_stats(stats_id),
    ...
    )
```

Comment: Be more specific in your question what you don't understand about relational database. Furthermore do a minimal example. You shouldn't expect people to look through all your tables and try to understand them. That's your job.

Comment: Converting a tree data model like JSON to a relational model like PostgreSQL is a very difficult project; why do you want to do that? You can store and query, parse and do analytics on JSON directly; why not just do that?

Comment: @DourHighArch I wanted to eventually run analytics and display through a dashboard on Heroku, and connect to it through an Amazon RDS instance. I've also got around 4.5 GB of that data so in my mind it made more sense to systematically input it to the database first. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusion stems from you working backwards trying to construct a RDB using the json data you've collected and you're seeing the result not the process. Relationships in an RDB are one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many, called 'Cardinality'. One game can include many teams, but a team can only reference the one game it belongs to. The same goes for participants of a team.

```sql
CREATE TABLE games (
    game_id Integer PRIMARY KEY,
    platformId Integer,
    gamecreation DateTime,
    ...
    )
```

Since the cardinality is one game to many teams, you can model this relationship by referencing the game in the team table, and then reference the team in the participants table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE teams (
    team_id Integer PRIMARY KEY,
    game_id Integer References games(game_id),
    win Bool,
    ...
    )
CREATE TABLE pariticpants (
    participant_id Integer PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id Integer References teams(team_id),
    ...
    )
```

Now whenever you query a game row from your Games table, add something like `Select team_id from Teams Join Games on Teams.game_id = Games.game_id` and the query now contains info about each team and the game they belonged to. The way you reference another table all depends on the cardinality so it's always best to create and entity relation diagram to help you navigate the tables.